# GridView lost datatable header and footer after postback or onselectedindexchanged

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable, datatables

Gridview will load file when page loads but it lost datatable plugin after postback or onselectedindexchanged.

I have tried to load datatable again after postback with PageRequestManager but didnt worked for me.

```
 $(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#GridView1").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable();
            });
        });
```

below is Grid Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-CssClass="bg-primary text-white" AutoPostBack="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_OnSelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="table table-bordered" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ClientIDMode="Static">
                            <Columns>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="NAME" SortExpression="NAME" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="EMAIL" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="EMAIL" />
                                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                            </Columns>
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <div class="text-center">No record found</div>
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="bg-primary text-white"></HeaderStyle>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Grid should load datatable plugin on page load/postback

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the page Load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
}
```